# Multiple weights in multilevel models

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, weighted-sampling, weighted-regression

I am currently working on a random intercept multilevel model using the European Social Survey round 6 dataset. It is a 2-level model with individuals (level 1) nested within countries (level 2). To simplify things, imagine the following regression:

$Y_{ij}=\beta_{0j}+\beta_{1j}X_{ij}+e_{ij}$

where the dependent variable is **trust in the European Parliament** on a scale from 0-10, and the level-1 predictor is **gender**. In the data set, there exists two weights:

- *Design weight*: The design weights are inclusion probabilities for individuals $i$ in countries $j$. The design weight corrects for slightly different probabilities of selection, thereby making the sample more representative of a ‘true’ sample of individuals from each country.
- *Population size weights*: The population size weight makes an adjustment to ensure that each country is represented in proportion to its population size. The population size weight is calculated as PWEIGHT= [Population size]/[(Net sample size in data file)*10 000]

My question is: do I need to specify the population size weights when I run the multilevel model? I tend to get different results. Below is the regression with design weights apllied (I am using Stata):

```
. xtmixed trstep gndr [pw = dweight]|| land:, mle var 

Obtaining starting values by EM: 

Performing gradient-based optimization: 

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood =  -92442,22  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood =  -92442,22  (backed up)

Computing standard errors:

Mixed-effects regression                        Number of obs      =     39923
Group variable: land                            Number of groups   =        24

                                                Obs per group: min =       579
                                                               avg =    1663,5
                                                               max =      2711


                                                Wald chi2(1)       =      5,91
Log pseudolikelihood =  -92442,22               Prob > chi2        =    0,0151

                                  (Std. Err. adjusted for 24 clusters in land)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      trstep |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        gndr |   ,1147821   ,0472334     2,43   0,015     ,0222063    ,2073578
       _cons |   4,144926    ,117911    35,15   0,000     3,913825    4,376027
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             |               Robust           
  Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
land: Identity               |
                  var(_cons) |   ,3184852   ,0689119      ,2084065    ,4867066
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
               var(Residual) |    5,93535   ,2514202      5,462477    6,449158
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is the regression with both design weights, population size weights and scaling applied:

```
. xtmixed trstep gndr [pw = dweight]|| land:, mle var pweight(pweight) pwscale(size)

Obtaining starting values by EM: 

Performing gradient-based optimization: 

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -81334,099  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood =  -81333,24  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood =  -81333,24  

Computing standard errors:

Mixed-effects regression                        Number of obs      =     39923
Group variable: land                            Number of groups   =        24

                                                Obs per group: min =       579
                                                               avg =    1663,5
                                                               max =      2711


                                                Wald chi2(1)       =     10,73
Log pseudolikelihood =  -81333,24               Prob > chi2        =    0,0011

                                  (Std. Err. adjusted for 24 clusters in land)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      trstep |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        gndr |   ,1680609   ,0513105     3,28   0,001     ,0674942    ,2686276
       _cons |   3,745146   ,1854299    20,20   0,000      3,38171    4,108582
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             |               Robust           
  Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
land: Identity               |
                  var(_cons) |   ,2645594   ,0598105      ,1698583     ,412059
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
               var(Residual) |   6,070198   ,3532338      5,415894    6,803549
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out how the population weights influence the ML estimates. The official ESS documentation says:

> When comparing data from two or more countries but without reference
>   to the average (or combined total) of those countries, only the design
>   weight need be applied. When comparing data of two or more countries
>   and with reference to the average (or combined total) of those
>   countries, both design and population size weights should be applied. ([ESS Documentation](http://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/docs/methodology/ESS_weighting_data.pdf))

The question is, whether I actually just compare countries, or compare them to an overall mean. The latter seems to be correct, as the parameter estimates actually relate to the overall mean $\mu_{00}$. But I may be wrong. The Stata manual has an extensive section on weighting [here](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/stata12/pdf/xt_xtmixed.pdf#page=41) but it did not clear things up for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Population weights are for estimating the prevalence of some variable in terms of the estimated number of people in the population affected or having some characteristic. For example, if you wanted to estimate the total number of people with, say, 10 out of 10 as their support of parliament.

You want survey weights, which instead are used to adjust [all of] your inferences for unequal sampling probabilities. The situation is more complex with multilevel models but it is still the design weights that you want.

An accessible overview of using design weights in multilevel models is available in the [Snijders and Bosker multilevel models book](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esnijders/mlbook.htm).